# I need a 5th port on a 4-port modem

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network, wide-area-network, modem

I'm managing a big building, with a lot of services/vendors and I have a DMZ'd 4-port cable modem, Model: SMC8014, that has 4 separate networks branching off each of its 4 ports.  Each network has its own equipment (Its own router/firewall).  It's very difficult for me to mess with those networks.

I need to add yet another network that is directly on the WAN and normally I would just plug it into the extra slot on the modem.  However, the modem is full.  So I'm wondering... **Would it mess anything up if I bought a switch to "add more ports" to my modem?**  I mean can I directly connect a switch to my modem, then from there attach X networks, all with their own routers?

Otherwise, plan B would be to buy a bigger modem, if they make them.

I'm assuming I'd have to get my ISP to give me another IP address for the extra networks as well.

Comment: You left out most of the pertinent information required to answer this question. A diagram, some background information, model numbers for all the equipment and the details of how all the different networks are setup would all be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those four ports on the back of that modem are merely switch ports. You should be just fine adding another "dumb" switch to gain more WAN ports.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a stupid question lol.  Thanks.

Comment: Unless they're not. I've seen Lancomm units that put each port on a seperate VLAN so you can have four segregated networks. If this is one of those setups...

Comment: @MarkHenderson - I have that exact model, so I spoke more strongly than I might have otherwise...

Comment: Ah, fair enough